# Moderate and High vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

After every npm install my app tells me there are 81 vulnerabilities. 80 moderate and 1 high.
Is there any way of fixing this? I tried updating the dependencies. Didn't work. What can I do and is it important?

```
Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         postcss

  Patched in      >=8.2.10

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > postcss

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693



  High            Memory Exposure

  Package         dns-packet

  Patched in      >=5.2.2

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > bonjour > multicast-dns
                  > dns-packet

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1745


  Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         browserslist
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm audit fix` will only apply patches, but you most likely need a minor or major version update. In order to do this, you'll need to go into your `package.json` file and update `react-scripts` to a more recent version. Without knowing anything about your project I can't say exactly what version would be best, but I'd start with the latest (`4.0.3` as of writing this) and see if that works. If not, keep going down a version until your app does work.

Comment: But why would that be necessary? My react-scripts is 4.0.3. and the project is only a week old. I never experienced errors like this before. Also, npm audit fix does nothing. Vulnerabilities remain. The app works. It's just the vulnerabilities that pop up.

Comment: I made a bad assumption then, could you post your package.json?